# Ionic2 and SqlStorage, sql with more than 1 line

Tags: sqlite, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a service to manage the database and at the constructor I create all my database or part if not exist. 
I haven´t have problem while I was working with an unique line at create database.

```
sql=" CREATE TABLE cliente (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nombre TEXT, telefono TEXT);";
this.storage.query(sql);
```

The problem has arrived when I have tried a sql with more than one line

```
sql=`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cliente;
CREATE TABLE cliente (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, telefono TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parte;
CREATE TABLE parte (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, clienteid INTEGER CONSTRAINT fk_clienteid REFERENCES cliente (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT, fecha DATE NOT NULL, horaini TIME NOT NULL, horafin TIME NOT NULL, trabajorealizado TEXT, personafirma TEXT);`;

this.storage.query(sql);
```

I receive this error "could not prepare statement (1 not an error)".
I test with only two sql lines (first two) and I get the error. If a execute one by one  all work fine....

I´d like to know if this is the way (one by one) or whether a best way to do this.

thanks.

Comment: Will that be the DB Engine's protection? e.g. avoiding SQL injecting a DELETE by appending after a SELECT...

Comment: No, for example, if I try this: 
sql='Select * from cliente; Select * from cliente;';
this.storage.query(sql); 

I have the same error...

Comment: the above example is all in one line .. :(

Comment: I mean, will the database be rejecting queries with multiple statements? I heard that some engines will block queries containing multiple queries / inner queries so as to avoid SQL injection attacks...